# Как запереть ftp пользователя в определённой папке?

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

Ответ не нагуглился. chroot_local_user=YES не помогает, пользователь всё равно может подняться выше своей домашней директории. Я обратил внимание, что некоторые сервера при входе по FTP показывают путь не **/var/www/ftp** а просто **/** и нет ссылки на подъём выше в принципе. Как подобное можно настроить с **vsftpd**?
Конфиг:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/ftp
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

Comment: При создании пользователя указывает домашний каталог. И если, например, будет указана папка /var/www/example.com, то выше этой папке он не поднимется.

Comment: Указана /var/www/ftp, легко поднимается.

Comment: выглядит вроде правильно... в логах ничего интересного нет? в `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` пользователь от которого пробуешь зайти не прописан?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, прописан. Но если его оттуда убрать, то не пускает. Ошибка "GnuTLS -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received."

Comment: @Fat-Zer навели на решение, спасибо. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено!

Убрал:

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

И добавил:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Ошибка возникает в том случае, когда у учетной записи, от которой идет подключения есть права на запись в корневую домашнюю директорию, а также используется безопасное соединение через TLS. В vsFTPd, по умолчанию, это приводит к ошибке. А мне и надо было дать запись в корень, а не вложенную папку. Директива **allow_writeable_chroot** позволяет писать в корень чрута.

Comment: добавлю что при `chroot_local_user=YES`, список `chroot_list_file` становится белым листом для тех пользователей, которых `chroot`'ить не надо... и т.к. vsftpd всё же дейтище для бОльших  параноиков нежели среднестатистический обыватель, то правильным решением было бы отнять права на запись в корень через ftp, а не отключать проверку безопасности...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это всё понятно, но другим юзером всё равно не зайти, так что лишняя паранойя тут не нужна, хотя я вполне параноидален. :))